# Passing Date variables in vba to sql statement

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, date, variables

I have looked through various different scenarios already posted but none of the solutions appear to bring any joy.
I am trying to pass date variables into a sql select statement but I'm given either an error about converting to date/time or the fact the variable isn't defined properly i.e. incorrect syntax.
The same is applicable to the variable 'contractNumber' but I would expect however the date variable is done, the same would be applied to the 'contractNumber' variable.
I have tried surrounding the variables with "" / "& / #"" & but none of those combinations seem to work....

The code I am using is below and the dates in the "Control" sheets are standard UK date - DD/MM/YYYY

```
Sub MEHT()

Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date
Dim contractNumber As String

startdate = Sheets("Control").Range("K8").Value
enddate = Sheets("Control").Range("K10").Value
contractNumber = Sheets("Control").Range("K13").Value

Call ConnectSqlServer

End Sub

Sub ConnectSqlServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=NT124431\DW;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=hdw2;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"


    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT SAF.Tracking_Number, ORH.CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER,MAX(DOC.DOCUMENT_NUMBER),DOC.DOCUMENT_DATE_KEY,SAF.ITEM_NUMBER,  MAX(ITM.HOMECRAFT_ITEM_NUMBER), " _
        & "MAX(ITM.ITEM_DESCR),MAX(ADR.ADDR_NAME),MAX(ADR.ADDR1),MAX(ADR.ZIP_5_KEY),SUM(SAF.QUANTITY_SOLD),SUM(SAF.EXTENDED_AMOUNT) " _
        & ",SUM(SAF.EXTENDED_AMOUNT) / SUM(SAF.QUANTITY_SOLD) FROM SALES_FACT SAF  JOIN LU_CUSTOMER_TBL CUS ON SAF.CUSTOMER_KEY = CUS.CUSTOMER_KEY " _
        & "JOIN ORDER_DM ORH ON SAF.ORDER_KEY = ORH.ORDER_KEY JOIN PRODUCT_DM PRD ON SAF.PRODUCT_KEY = PRD.PRODUCT_KEY JOIN DOCUMENT_DM DOC " _
        & "ON SAF.DOCUMENT_KEY = DOC.DOCUMENT_KEY JOIN LU_ITEM ITM ON SAF.ITEM_NUMBER = ITM.ITEM_NUMBER JOIN LU_ADDRESS ADR ON DOC.SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_KEY = ADR.ADDRESS_KEY " _
        & "WHERE ITM.ITEM_CATEGORY_KEY NOT IN ('31010') AND SAF.TRACKING_CODE NOT IN ('F') AND PRD.PRODUCT_LINE_KEY NOT IN ('UN') AND PRD.PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_KEY NOT IN ('60P') " _
        & "AND SAF.TRACKING_NUMBER = " & contractNumber & " AND SAF.EXTENDED_AMOUNT > 0 AND DOC.DOCUMENT_DATE_KEY BETWEEN CONVERT(Date, " & startdate & " , 120) AND CONVERT(Date," & enddate & " , 120) " _
        & "GROUP BY ORH.CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER, DOC.DOCUMENT_DATE_KEY,SAF.ITEM_NUMBER,SAF.Tracking_Number ORDER BY SAF.Tracking_Number,DOC.DOCUMENT_DATE_KEY")

    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets("Detail").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume that the cells on your sheet are formatted as "date" too. otherwise, try to convert the cells' values to date with `cdate`. My other suggestion on the first view is to use `debug.print` to get the sql statement and check if it is passed correctly to the database.

Comment: This is a hack instead of a real answer, but we used to always format dates as `yyyymmdd` to avoid such matters. SQL Server will interpret those correctly and without ambiguity. For example, like this: `(...) BETWEEN '" & Year(startdate) & Format$(Month(startdate), "00") & Format$(Day(startdate), "00") & "' AND (...)` (an utility function will simplify things). Note the apostrophes (we're passing dates as strings to SQL).

Comment: Hi ssarabando, worked perfectly! Had me scratching my head on this and this has helped me out immensely - thank you very much!
Also, thanks to psychicebola and Mike for your answers too!

Answer (score 2):

> The code I am using is below and the dates in the "Control"  sheets
>   are standard UK date - DD/MM/YYYY

Despite being a fellow Brit, I *wouldn't* recommend using your date format...

The safest way to pass dates to SQL Server is to use "yyyy-MM-dd".  This guarantees it'll work, regardless of where you are in the world.

```
select * from [SomeTable]
where Update_Time >= '2015-08-06'
```